# How to bring a pull request to a state of "can be merged automatically"?

Tags: git, github

I have branched from `dev` branch into `feature` branch and made some commits. Now, when i send a pull request to merge a `feature` branch into `dev` branch I notice on github that the branch cannot be merged automatically because of some conflicting changes. What do i need to do in order to bring my `feature` branch into the state of "can be merged automatically"?

What i currently do is:

1. Checkout the `dev` branch
2. Merge `feature` branch
3. Remember the lines that caused the conflict
4. Checkout the `feature` branch
5. Manually revert each line to the state of the `dev` branch
6. Commit and push the patch

But this looks like many handwork. So i wondered if this can be simplified somehow?

**UPDATE**

Mind that i would like to keep my `feature` branch changes isolated from `develop` branch (for the purpose of keeping track of which branch introduced regressions and testing each new feature in isolation to other features). So, while merging/rebasing `dev` into `feature` would solve the problem, it would bring all the changes made in `dev` into `feature` and i would loose isolation.

Answer (score 3):

Few assumptions: you took a branch out from `dev` and called it `feature` and you want to merge `feature` into `dev`

Your branch `feature` is not mergeable to `dev branch because someone has already made changes to`dev` which cannot be conflict resolved by git automatically.

In this scenario, there are two approaches that you can take

1. Rebase - In this case you will follow these steps below

   - checkout `dev`
   - take pull from remote
   - checkout `feature`
   - `git rebase dev` - Internally, this **1)** removes all your commits beyond last
     commit where `feature` and `dev` were same **2)** applies all `dev`
     commits **3)** one by one apply all `feature` commits - and as an when
     conflicts occur, git prompts you to fix the conflicts. The last step
     repeats until all your commits have been successfully applied back to
     `feature` branch.
   - Push all changes to `feature` branch remote
   - Send in a pull request :-)

This is the one that I always follow and it is recommended that you keep taking pull from parent branch regularly to avoid conflicts. This creates a diamond structure in git commit history.

2. The second one is merge, but I use and find rebase much cleaner and use that always.

Comment: Option 2.: You probably mean "merge `dev` into `feature`", right? This should be clarified. Merging `dev` into `feature`, you can solve the conflicts on your own, and then merge `feature` into `dev` without conflicts. But this makes the history look dirty. Ideally, you would resolve the conflicts when merging `feature` into `dev`.

Comment: By merging `dev` into `feature` (or rebasing `dev` onto `feature`) i loose the isolation of a `feature` branch changes and this is what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: There is binary search feature in git that helps you identify the commit that introduced bug.

Comment: @Dziamid - it is never possible to keep one branch completely aloof and still being able to merge this branch into a parent branch. Eventually, you would have to take code from parent branch also.

Comment: I realize that. I would like to take as few as possible, so that there is no conflict when the brach will be eventually merged.

Comment: There will be less conflict only when you keep pulling in changes from parent branch at regular intervals